# Is gravity linked with another force?

Tags: gravity

Electricity and magnetism are linked. As are space and time. Is gravity linked to anything so far as we know?

Comment: FWIW, you might find [gravitoelectromagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitoelectromagnetism) interesting.

Answer (score 2):

In mainstream physics, gravity is not linked to the other three forces, namely electromagnetism and the strong and weak interactions. The Standard Model of particle physics uses quantum field theory to explain these three forces, but it omits gravity entirely because so far there is no accepted way to quantize gravity.

General Relativity remains the sole classical holdout among the forces for now. In this theory, gravity is linked to, or explained as, the curvature of spacetime that is caused by the density and flow of energy and momentum.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the fundamental forces:

[image]

Now as you say, the EM and weak forces can be unified, into the electroweak force.

The electroweak and strong force needs a Grand unified theory.

But so far, to unify gravity with the other forces, we would need a Theory of everything.

But, you can see similarities between gravity and EM:

You are right, you can talk about some similarities between the equations for EM and GR, between the Maxwell equations and some of Einstein's field equations for GR.

The reformulation of gravity in GR in the weak field limit, will make this field appear differently in a frame of reference, then a freely moving inertial body.

Now this field of gravity may be described by two components, analogously to EM, like the electric and magnetic field. These fields are called gravitoelectric and gravitomagnetic fields.